# A* algorithm - ellipse property of expension

Tags: algorithm, a-star

Based on the ellipse property of A*, why this algorithm closes
all nodes in a series of expanding ellipses?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A* uses the function `f(x) = g(x) + h(x)` to assess what node to visit next, where `g(x)` is the actual cost for going from the start to `x` and `h(x)` is the estimated cost to go from `x` to the target (= heuristic).

Let's take a look at this in the continuous case in the Euclidean plane, where we want to go from `(0, 0)` to `(10, 20)`. Then:

```
g(x) = Length(x)
```

The shape of the exploration front depends heavily on the heuristic. Let's start with the perfect heuristic

```
h(x) = Length(x - (10, 20))
```

We can plot the value of `g(x) + h(x)` over the plane and see the order of visited nodes (points with smaller `f` will be visited first). Doing so, we should be aware that a node cannot be visited if none of its neighbors have been visited before, so the actual value is only an indication of the order. We'll keep this in mind. Using the perfect heuristic, we get the following picture:

[image: Perfect Heuristic]

All points on the connection between start and target have the same `f` cost, which is equal to the distance of start and target. And if we inspect `f`, we see that

```
f = Length(x - (0, 0)) + Length(x - (10, 20)),
```

which is exactly the implicit form of an ellipse with the start and target as foci.

I said that the shape depends on the heuristic. A heuristic is valid if it is a lower bound of the actual distance. Let's try

```
h(x) = 0.5 * Length(x - (10, 20))
```

[image: Half Heuristic]

Now, the algorithm will start to explore more points surrounding the start before it reaches the target. Especially, all points within the contour before the target point will be visited.

We can even go one step further and set

```
h(x) = 0
```

This is the setting for Dijkstra's algorithm, where we cannot say anything about the distance to the target:

[image: Dijkstra]

Here, the algorithm will visit nodes in disks around the start point.

One common approximation of the distance to the target is the Manhattan distance because it is cheap to compute:

```
h(x, y) = |x - 10| + |y - 20|
```

This heuristic is not valid because it is not a lower bound on the actual distance. It gives us:

[image: Manhattan Distance]

This is exactly a case where points close to the target have a lower `f` score than those close to the start. Although they have a lower value in this figure, they will of course not be visited first because their neighbors have not been explored yet. Here is a close-up:

[image: Manhattan Close-Up]

We can make the heuristic valid by introducing a constant factor:

```
h(x, y) = 1/sqrt(2) * (|x - 10| + |y - 20|)
```

This will give us a valid heuristic with a proper front shape:

[image: Valid Manhattan Distance]